# Solving complex numbers with conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been trying to find $z$ for hours now but I'm still not able to figure it out. The written answers is $z= \pm3 +j2$

question: Find $\bar z z + 3(z - \bar z)=13+12i$.

I tried to isolate $z$ but I keep getting stuck there. Please help

Comment: Try with $z=x+iy$.

Comment: What is the number $j$?

Comment: $j = i = \sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: OP please double check that the edit got the equation right.

Comment: yes it is right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\,\bar z z = |z|^2\,$ and $z - \bar z = 2i \operatorname{Im}(z)$.

Then $\;|z|^2 + 3 \cdot 2i \operatorname{Im}(z) = 13 + 12i$ $\implies$ $|z|^2=13, \;$ $\operatorname{Im}(z)=2\,$.

Answer (score 0):

with the hint from above we have
$$(x-iy)(x+iy)+3(x+iy-x+iy)=13+12i$$
or simplified
$$x^2+y^2+3iy=13+12i$$
can you finish?

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I did try to do it this way at one point but i stopped halfway not really sure of where i was going. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+y^2+3(x+yi-x+yi)=13+12i,$$ 
which gives $x^2+y^2=13$ and $y=2$.

From here we get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this,
I would just plug in
$z = x+iy$
(I use $i$
instead of $j$)
and grind away.

You want
$\bar z z + 3(z - \bar z)=13+12j
$.

Since
$\bar z = x-iy$,
the left side is
$(x-iy)(x+iy) + 3(x+iy - (x-iy))
=x^2+y^2+3(2iy)
=x^2+y^2+6iy
$.

So you want
$13+12i=x^2+y^2+6iy$.

Equating real and imaginary parts.
$x^2+y^2 = 13$
and
$6y = 12$.

From the last,
$y = 2$.

Substituting in the first,
$x^2 = 
13-2^2 = 9$,
so
$x = \pm 3$.

Therefore
$z = \pm 3 +2i$.